# Substract two fields in mongodb with Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I run into the problem of wanting to subtract 2 fields from my mongodb database and return them in a variable.

I am using bson.M to perform the operation in golang without any success.

```
    col2 := db.Collection("products")

pipe2 := []bson.M{
    {"$group": bson.M{
        "_id":   IDUser,
        "total": bson.M{"$subtract": {"$actualPrice", "$oldPrice"}},
    }},
}

cur2, err := col2.Aggregate(ctx, pipe2)
```

Comment: What is the error? Provide more information

Comment: The code you posted does not compile (missing type in the inner composite literal). What do you want to do? Include the `actualPrice - oldPrice` difference in each result document? That's doable, but also easy to calculate in Go. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It would also be helpful to show how your documents look like. It might also be important what `IDUser` is.

Comment: The error is this code no working with substract, I have need substract two fields and return result.

Comment: @icza yes to first question,  Include the actualPrice - oldPrice difference in each result document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$subtract`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator requires an array (which may be a slice in Go).

And to add a field to the output document, use the [`$addFields`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage:

```
pipe2 := []bson.M{
    {"$addFields": bson.M{
        "total": bson.M{"$subtract": []string{"$actualPrice", "$oldPrice"}},
    }},
}
```

Testing it with the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : "u1", "actualPrice" : 100, "oldPrice" : 80 }
{ "_id" : "u2", "actualPrice" : 200, "oldPrice" : 190 }
```

Testing code:

```
cur2, err := col2.Aggregate(ctx, pipe2)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var results []bson.M
if err = cur2.All(ctx, &results); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(results)
```

Output:

```
[map[_id:u1 actualPrice:100 oldPrice:80 total:20] 
 map[_id:u2 actualPrice:200 oldPrice:190 total:10]]
```

Comment: I have a problem, the console after change say 2022/04/17 22:47:34 http: panic serving [::1]:60524: (TypeMismatch) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: can't $subtract string from string

Comment: @fab Yes, you can only use `$subtract` on numbers, not on strings. Either convert your database values to numbers so you can use `$subtract`, or do the subtraction in Go after parsing the values into numbers.

Comment: thanks for your help @icza